# Java "fill in the blanks" exercise

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to make a project which reads a .txt file and fills in the blank.
The file is a simple .txt file containing 2 lines.
First Line is made of words that have a blank like ba_n__a and the second line is made of words like "banana" which can fit in the blanks of the first line (second line with answers is randomly placed so words are not in the same order as blanks).

I've tried for a couple of hours now but cannot figure out how to do it since I am a beginner.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;

public class DateinEinlesen {


public static String einlesen(String pfad) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {

        String str = null;
        BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pfad));
        while ((str = buffered.readLine()) != null) {
            str = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]", "");
            String[] splitted = str.split("\\s+");

            for (String teil : splitted) {
               System.out.println(teil);
               System.out.println(teil.length());
            }
        }

        return str;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";


}

}
```

So basically what this code does so far is reads the .txt file and it splits the 2 lines into seperate strings and prints the strings and the length of the string.
Another problem I have is that my code does not split line 1 and line 2 sperately.
What I mean by that is that if I do

```
System.out.println(splitted[2]);
```

and word 3 in line 1 of the .txt file is "ba__na" and word 3 in line 2 is "apple"
it prints both words so both words are saved as splitted[2].

I would like to know how I can make the code compare every string in the second line with the first line and fill in the blanks.

Sorry if my question is not detailed enough I am trying my best.

Comment: I'd say your question does have enough detail for us to solve your problem, but there is another issue with your post.  I see no attempt to write any logic here; all you do is loop through the strings in the file and print them out.  You will learn much more from trying to solve this yourself, and we will gladly help you with a more specific problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes I have been trying to solve my problem but I have been stuck for a few hours now. I dont know how to fix this problem regarding the splitting. So splitted[0] exists in every Line not only once.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is that not what you want?  On the first iteration, `splitted` contains the words with blanks, and on the second iteration, `splitted` contains the full words.  I would suggest, if you always have exactly 2 lines, that you get rid of the while loop to make things simpler to understand.  Just write out the code twice, maybe use two variable names, like `splitted1` and `splitted2`.  You can go back and try to shorten the code once you have it working.